# transactionnal email variable

Tags: magento-1.8, email, backend, email-templates, email-translation

I'm trying to change something in Magento's automatic email.

The text of {{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}} 
 is this one :

`Subtotal : xx €
Shipping & Handling : xx €
(...)`

I wanna change the text label in this variable and in other of email template.
Unfortunetly, I can't find how to change label 'Subtotal' (or any other), do someone know how I can do it ?

Thank's a lot ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how you can find out, where the text comes from:

First: use `grep` to search for the layout handle `sales_email_order_items` in the magento codebase.

You will find some files like `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/sales.xml` where the template is defined:

```
<!--
Email layouts section
-->
    <sales_email_order_items>
        <block type="sales/order_email_items" name="items" template="email/order/items.phtml">
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>sales/order_email_items_order_default</block><template>email/order/items/order/default.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>sales/order_email_items_order_grouped</block><template>email/order/items/order/default.phtml</template></action>
            <block type="sales/order_totals" name="order_totals" template="sales/order/totals.phtml">
                <action method="setLabelProperties"><value>colspan="3" align="right" style="padding:3px 9px"</value></action>
                <action method="setValueProperties"><value>align="right" style="padding:3px 9px"</value></action>
                <block type="tax/sales_order_tax" name="tax" template="tax/order/tax.phtml">
                    <action method="setIsPlaneMode"><value>1</value></action>
                </block>
            </block>
        </block>
        <block type="core/text_list" name="additional.product.info" />
    </sales_email_order_items>
```

Have a look at the block in the middle `<block type="sales/order_totals" name="order_totals" template="sales/order/totals.phtml">...</block>`. If you open `sales/order/totals.phtml` you will see that this template contains the loop for the output of the totals. The totals itself come from `Mage_Sales_Block_Order_Totals` (check out the `@see Mage_Sales_Block_Order_Totals` block  in the phtml-file.

The label itself is set in `Mage_Sales_Block_Order_Totals`.
Draw your attention to the `_initTotals method`:

```
/**
     * Initialize order totals array
     *
     * @return Mage_Sales_Block_Order_Totals
     */
    protected function _initTotals()
    {
        $source = $this->getSource();

        $this->_totals = array();
        $this->_totals['subtotal'] = new Varien_Object(array(
            'code'  => 'subtotal',
            'value' => $source->getSubtotal(),
            'label' => $this->__('Subtotal')
        ));

     ...
    }
```

This means:
The label is set in the `_initTotals` method of `Mage_Sales_Block_Order_Totals`.
$this->_totals['subtotal'] = new Varien_Object(array(
            'code'  => 'subtotal',
            'value' => $source->getSubtotal(),
            'label' => $this->__('Subtotal')
        ));

The label is put into the template in `sales/order/totals.phtml` here:

```
     <td <?php echo $this->getLabelProperties()?>>
         <?php if ($_total->getStrong()):?>
         <strong><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_total->getLabel());?></strong>
         <?php else:?>
         <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_total->getLabel());?>
         <?php endif?>
     </td>
```

**How to change the label?**

If you want to change the labels in your shop **globally** I suggest you put it into your **translation files** (app/design/frontend/yourpackage/yourtheme/locale/en_US/translate.csv in your shop template OR in one of your shop base modules - if you have something like this).

If you only want to change the label in the e-mails, the easiest might be to define your **own template** for `<block type="sales/order_invoice_totals" .... > ... </block>`, for example:

```
<block type="sales/order_invoice_totals" name="invoice_totals" template="your/costom/template_for_totals.phtml">
          <action method="setLabelProperties"><value>colspan="3" align="right" style="padding:3px 9px"</value></action>
          <action method="setValueProperties"><value>align="right" style="padding:3px 9px"</value></action>
          <block type="tax/sales_order_tax" name="tax" template="tax/order/tax.phtml">
             <action method="setIsPlaneMode"><value>1</value></action>
          </block>
 </block>
```

**Why creating your own template file?**

The template `sales/order/totals.phtml` is used quite often in different layout XML-files and you this will also change the label, wherever this template is used.

Comment: Thank's a lot =)